# How do I capitalize the first letter in my string using c?

Tags: c

My project is to create a source string of my first name, last name, and student id in lower case letters and print them out on separate lines and the first letter of my name will be capitalized.  I have looked at many sample codes and have not been able to figure this out.  Also, my student id is supposed to print out as a number and not a string.  Not sure what that even means.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "david house n966898";

  char f_name[6], l_name[6], st_id[8];

  strcpy(f_name, strtok(str, " "));
  strcpy(l_name, strtok(NULL, " "));
  strcpy(st_id, strtok(NULL, " "));

  printf("First Name: %s\n", f_name);
  printf("Last  Name: %s\n", l_name);
  printf("Student ID: %s\n", st_id);


  return 0;

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Student ID: for string or character to integer you can use atoi() function.

Comment: ok, I have seen this atoi() before, but wasn't sure what it meant

Comment: `atoi("n966898")` will be 0 so you'll have to work around that.

Comment: I just saw that.  When I tried it, it came to 0 instead of my number.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 5):

Accessing the first letter is done with the array-operator [].
Converting to uppercase is done with the ANSI-C function toupper().

```
f_name[0] = toupper(f_name[0]);
```

Printing out something which is a number is done with the %d placeholder.
Converting a string to a number is done via ANSI-C function atoi().

```
printf("Id: %d\n", atoi( st_id ) );
```

You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language to get a better understanding of C.

Comment: Elaborate and Explain your answer for better understanding

Comment: In this case there is perhaps no need to convert the numeric part of the string to a number. Simply printing that part of the string seems to suffice.

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`toupper(int)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html) to capitalize one character; and you can use [`atoi(const char *)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) to parse the student id. Something like

```
printf("First Name: %c%s\n", toupper(f_name[0]), f_name + 1);
printf("Last  Name: %c%s\n", toupper(l_name[0]), l_name + 1);
printf("Student ID: %i\n", atoi(st_id + 1));
```

Outputs (with no other changes)

```
First Name: David
Last  Name: House
Student ID: 966898
```

Comment: For some reason it is not printing anything with the f_name, l_name, etc

Comment: Replace your `printf`(s) with these; have you made any other changes? Because I've run this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ apropos upper
toupper (3)          - convert letter to upper or lower case
toupper (3p)         - transliterate lowercase characters to uppercase
towlower (3p)        - transliterate uppercase wide-character code to lowercase
towupper (3)         - convert a wide character to uppercase
towupper (3p)        - transliterate lowercase wide-character code to uppercase
$ man toupper
NAME
       toupper, tolower - convert letter to upper or lower case

SYNOPSIS
       #include <ctype.h>

       int toupper(int c);
       int tolower(int c);

DESCRIPTION
       toupper() converts the letter c to upper case, if possible.

       tolower() converts the letter c to lower case, if possible.

       If c is not an unsigned char value, or EOF, the behavior
       of these functions is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

In some situations in helps to understand traditional ASCII:

```
‘A’ = 0x41 = 0100 0001B 

‘a’ = 0x61 = 0110 0001B

Lower to upper: c & 1101 1111
Upper to lower: c | 0010 0000
```

Converting between upper and lower character in ASCII is a matter of masking a single bit.  When it's the first character of a character array, just dereference the pointer to the array and mask it.

```
*c & 0xDF; // to upper - some may consider bad form!
```

Does not require any library, any include files, and its very fast.  Also would not be considered very portable so should only be used with that consideration.

Also note that the lower five bits for either upper or lower case begins counting the alphabet at 1, which yields some insights on other fast and easy conversions between numbers and alphabet.